# looping into the NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

NSArray1.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short          wAppTimerId;    
    BOOL                    bPersistent;   
    uint8_t                 uPeriod;        
    BOOL                    bStopped;       
    uint8_t                 uExpirationTime;    
} stRs232Timer;

@interface NSArray1 : NSObject {

    unsigned short wTimerId;
    NSLock* theLock;
    NSMutableDictionary*  m_cAppIdMap;
    NSMutableArray* m_cPendingEventList;

}

-(BOOL)createTimer;
-(BOOL)KillTimer:(unsigned short)wTimerId;

@end
```

NSArray1.m

```
#import "NSArray1.h"

@implementation NSArray1

 -(BOOL)createTimer
{
    stRs232Timer*   pEvent = malloc(sizeof(stRs232Timer));

    pEvent->bPersistent = YES;                        
    pEvent->wAppTimerId = 95;
    pEvent->uPeriod     = 50;
    pEvent->bStopped    = NO;
    wTimerId = 95;

    NSLog(@"bPersistent:%d",pEvent->bPersistent);
    NSLog(@"wAppTimerId:%d",pEvent->wAppTimerId);
    NSLog(@"uPeriod:%d",pEvent->uPeriod);
    NSLog(@"bStopped:%d",pEvent->bStopped);

    theLock = [[NSLock alloc]init];

    [self KillTimer:wTimerId];
    if ([theLock tryLock]) {
        //CFDictionarySetValue(m_cAppIdMap,&wTimerId,pEvent);
        [m_cAppIdMap setObject:pEvent forKey:wTimerId];
        [theLock unlock];
    }   

    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)KillTimer:(unsigned short)wTimerId
{
    stRs232Timer* pEvent;
    BOOL bReturn=NO;
    theLock = [[NSLock alloc]init];

    if ([theLock tryLock]) {
             // remove from app map
        NSLog(@"Locked");
        [m_cAppIdMap setObject:pEvent forKey:wTimerId]; //warning:passing argument 1 of setObject from incompatible pointer type
        int no = [m_cAppIdMap count];
        NSLog(@"The no of entries in array is:%d",no);
        for(id i in m_cAppIdMap)
        {
            NSLog(@"Going to remove a key!!");
            [self findAndRemoveEvent:pEvent];
            [m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:wTimerId]; //warning:Local declaration of wTimerId hides instance object
            NSLog(@"Removed the key");  //warning:passing argument 1 of 'objectForKey' makes pointer from integer without a cast
            free(pEvent);
            bReturn = YES;
        }
        NSLog(@"Unlocked!!");
        [theLock unlock];
    }   

    return bReturn;
}

@end
```

output:

```
2011-05-24 14:12:55.289 NSArray[3313:a0f] bPersistent:1
2011-05-24 14:12:55.291 NSArray[3313:a0f] wAppTimerId:95
2011-05-24 14:12:55.292 NSArray[3313:a0f] uPeriod:50
2011-05-24 14:12:55.292 NSArray[3313:a0f] bStopped:0
2011-05-24 14:12:55.293 NSArray[3313:a0f] Locked
2011-05-24 14:12:55.293 NSArray[3313:a0f] The no of entries in array is:0
2011-05-24 14:12:55.294 NSArray[3313:a0f] Unlocked!!
```

Its `not going into the for loop`.I need to find the pEvent for a particular key(95).Also though i'm setting the dictionary with a value and key its `not giving` me the `correct count` value.Its showing the count value as '0'.

Comment: `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` cannot hold ‘things’ other than Objective-C objects, which is why you get a warning when sending `-setObject:forKey:`. Keys should be objects, too.

Comment: You can box your `structs` inside `NSData` objects, storing the latter in the dictionary. For the keys, you can box the `unsigned shorts` inside `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: You might find it simpler to use an Objective-C class instead of a `struct`, though. This will make it easier to store them in Foundation collections such as `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @Bavarious:Thanks.. all the warnings got disappeared. I set NSData* myarr = [NSData dataWithBytes&pEvent length:sizeof(pEvent)]; as you told me to do. But i could not now get the correct output.Its not going into the for loop of the killTimer method!!!

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary key must be an object.

Try replacing the setObject line with this:

```
[m_cAppIdMap setObject:pEvent forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
```

Comment: an object that conforms to `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: Thanks.The warning got cleared but i have one more waning "passing argument1 of setObject:forKey from incompatible pointer type".I'm passing the pointer to the structure as the value to the dictionary.

Comment: `pEvent` is not an Objective-C object.

Comment: @Bavarious:How do i set a structure object into the objective C object.

Comment: I think it needs to inherit from NSObject.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not name your classes using the `NS` prefix, as this is reserved for Apple only.

Second, are you sure you want to keep things in a struct instead of a custom class or a dictionary? A struct is more lightweight, sure, but can cause a bit of a pain to integrate into an object-oriented program.

Comment: yeah i am inserting the struct objects as values into the dictionary.